# Как исправить ошибку Angular 2 (где-то в WebPack) в связке с Cordova?

Tags: node.js, angular2, webpack, cordova

Окружение:

```
> node -v
v6.11.0
> npm -v
3.10.10
> ng -v
@angular/cli: 1.1.2
os: win32 x64
> cordova -v
7.0.1
```

Путь к воспроизведению ошибки:

```
> ng new App
> cd App
> cordova create cordova com.mycompany.app App
> ng build --output-path=cordova/www/ --base-href .
> cd cordova
> cordova platform add android
> cordova run android
```

На устройстве/эмуляторе (первое в моём случае) открывается приложение и белый экран.
Перейдя в `chrome://inspect/#devices` видно ошибку "`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined in vendor.bundle.js:5706`":

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'apply' of undefined in vendor.bundle.js:5706]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `src/polyfills.ts` раскомментируйте строку `import 'core-js/es6/object';`.